# I can run the model which I made with simpletransformers in google colab, but when I run it in spyder or visual studio, it gives an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, simpletransformers

```
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel
import torch
Bert_model = ClassificationModel(
    "bert", "bert_model")
a=Bert_model.predict(["kötü"])
print(a)
def run():
    torch.multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    print('loop')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

> > 2022-08-09 09:00:57.159758: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found2022-08-09 09:00:57.159911: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
> > 0%|                                                                                                                                                      | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]2022-08-09 09:01:03.293148: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
> > 2022-08-09 09:01:03.293547: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "", line 1, in 
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
> > exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
> > prepare(preparation_data)
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
> > _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
> > main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
> > return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
> > _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
> > exec(code, run_globals)
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\Desktop\code\python\FLASK\aa.py", line 5, in 
> > a=Bert_model.predict(["kötü"])
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simpletransformers\classification\classification_model.py", line 2062, in predict
> > eval_dataset = self.load_and_cache_examples(
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simpletransformers\classification\classification_model.py", line 1815, in load_and_cache_examples    dataset = ClassificationDataset(
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simpletransformers\classification\classification_utils.py", line 278, in **init**
> > self.examples, self.labels = build_classification_dataset(
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simpletransformers\classification\classification_utils.py", line 244, in build_classification_dataset
> > with Pool(args.process_count) as p:
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
> > return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in **init**
> > self._repopulate_pool()
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
> > return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
> > w.start()
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
> > self._popen = self._Popen(self)
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
> > return Popen(process_obj)
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in **init**
> > prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
> > _check_not_importing_main()
> > File "C:\Users\gokhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
> > raise RuntimeError('''
> > RuntimeError:
> > An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
> > current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error already solve your question

Set the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        freeze_support()
        ...
```

on your main.py code to multi thread the jobs.

Comment: I did but it still gives error.

Comment: The error also contains the CUDA-related error.
Did you set the CUDA environment on your local PC?